# sockjs with Angularjs - Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, sockjs

I'm trying Angularjs with sockjs and I'm using this to help: https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-sockjs

I would like to send some data via sockjs on page load but I'm getting **Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR** on the client side when I try to make the following call:

```
socket.send("test data");
```

I assume this is because Sockjs isn't "ready" yet. If I wrap it in a `$timeout` it works if the delay is big enough. 1000 works but 100 doesn't.

```
$timeout(function() {
  socket.send("test");
}, 1000);
```

This is obviously a hack and I wondered how I can detect when sockjs is ready so that I can then make the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`setHandler`](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-sockjs#socketsethandlerevent-callback) method and provide a callback for `'open'`. It'll be safe to send messages there. The service is pretty light and really only intended to ensure that the three SockJS client callbacks (`onopen`, `onclose`, `onmessage`) are called inside a digest cycle. If you wanted, you could easily use it to build a more complex service that among many possibilities could:

- queues sent messages when the socket is closed and sends them when it opens
- returns a `$q` promise that resolves when the socket opens

Comment: Cheers Ben - I did work this out actually but didn't answer my own question.

Comment: How can we use this `setHandler` method  in [ng-stomp](https://github.com/beevelop/ng-stomp) ?